# Does PDF Preview have language choice?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am beginner at Jaspersoft iReport 5.5.0. I prepared Turkish document but after PDF preview some letters like İ,ö,ç did not appear.However,in internal preview there is no letter problem. So, How can i adjust the language to Pdf preview.

Comment: I recommend you to start learning *JasperReports* with [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf). There also a lot of [samples](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference.html). You should use the [Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions) for solving your issue

Answer (score 1):

I got your point.

Please go through below steps to embed the font in PDF outpuput.

Steps:

1. Launch iReport, choose Tools->Options->Fonts
2. Click "Install Font" and follow the wizard to install your desired font.
   *Remember to tick the option "Embed this font in the PDF document"

[image]

3. Select the newly installed font and click the button "Export as extension"
4. Save the export file as JAR file
5. Copy the JAR file to the folder within your application classpath

Comment: Thanks a lot @sandip. :) I solved my problem with adding pdfEncoding to my font line. <font isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="true" pdfEncoding="Cp1254"/>